# Getting error unexpected public after writing php file using php

Tags: php, file

My methods are inside class but I am still getting error of

> error: syntax error, unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC), expecting end of
>   file in E:\xampp\htdocs\crud\application\controllers\student.php on
>   line 1.

May be that's because I am writing php file from php

**PHP file writing code:**

```
$file_data_write = "\n".'public function '.$table_name.'(){' . "\n" . '$this->load->view("'.$view_location.'");' . "\n" . '}'. "\n" . '}';
$file_location = APPPATH."controllers/". $view_and_controller_location;
$file_name = "/" . $view_and_controller_location . ".php";
$myfile = fopen($file_location . $file_name, "r+") or die("Unable to open file!");
fseek($myfile, -2, SEEK_END);
fwrite($myfile, $file_data_write);
fclose($myfile);
```

**Class I am writing to**

```
class Student extends CI_Controller {
  public function six(){
    $this->load->view("student/six");
  } 
}
```

Comment: Which is `student.php`? Also unrelated but you don't need to switch between single and double quotes.

Comment: second one class is student.php

Comment: What you are showing is student.php before writing or after writing?

Comment: student.php is already there without function public function six(), I am editing that file so every time there will be new function like function six, and using fseek method to have function at last of student.php and have } at the end

Comment: there is } at the end but still showing error

Comment: There must be something in student.php that you are not showing.  The code above runs just fine.

Comment: trust me that is all what I am showing you

Comment: if I just create manually like create new controller and put content in it by typing it it works just fine. but writing it by php creates this error

Comment: The error message indicates that "public" is on line 1 of student.php.  That does not match with what's above.  There is a disconnect between that message and what you are showing.

Comment: +1 @PatrickQ - the code posted in OP's Student class cannot match what is triggering that error. Not much more we can help with until we get the exact copy/paste.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably doing is adding your function after class closing } or php closing syntax

```
class Test 
{

}
?>

public function ... {
}
```

there can't be "public" function outside class, what error is exactly  telling you

or you are overwritting file not adding at end so public function will be in 1 line